# Trying to print out a data type of a struct encapsulated in another struct

Tags: c, struct

i was just wondering if anyone knew how to resolve an issue i'm getting when trying to print out a value of a data type "char []" of a struct that's encapsulated within another struct. Any advice would be appreciated as i've spent hours trying to resolve this issue already. Thanks in advance,
the error im gettinng is warning: (format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int')

```
  struct food_stuff
  {
      char name [30];
      int calories;
      int foodtype;
      int price;
  };

  typedef enum food_groups food_groups;

  struct food_plan_item
      {
          food_stuff fs;
          int qty;
      };    

  typedef struct food_plan_item food_plan_item;  


  void print_food_line_items(food_plan_item *fpi)
  {

      for(int i =0 ; i<fpi_count;i++)
      {
            printf("%s", *(fpi+fpi_count)->fs.name);
      }

  }
```

Comment: You could start by telling us what issue you are having.

Comment: Maybe I am just tired, but is the star neccesary on the printf line?

Comment: Sorry, i included the error i seem to be having  after i posted. I can upload the entire file if needed but its a bit of an eye full as it spans across 4 different files.

Comment: Thanks Tim that was it, sorry for such a stupid mistake, thanks for your time guys!

Comment: `->` and `.` have higher precedence than `*` so `*(fpi+fpi_count)->fs.name` turns into `*((fpi+fpi_count)->fs.name)` which has type `char` (and is promoted to `int`). Did you perhaps mean `fpi[fpi_count].fs.name` (or better yet: `fpi[i].fs.name`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra dereference in the line

```
printf("%s", *(fpi+fpi_count)->fs.name);
```

`fpi->fs.name` returns a `char *` pointer; `*fpi->fs.name` returns the first char of the array, which is a value (casts to int) not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following structure definitions:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[30];
    int calories;
    int foodtype;
    int price;
} food_stuff;

typedef struct
{
    food_stuff fs;
    int qty;
} food_plan_item;
```

You can access the fields of a `food_plan_item` structure like this:

```
food_plan_item fpi;
food_plan_item *pFpi = &fpi;

fpi.qty;
fpi.fs.name[0];
fpi.fs.calories;
fpi.fs.foodtype;
fpi.fs.price;

pFpi->qty;
pFpi->fs.name[0];
pFpi->fs.calories;
pFpi->fs.foodtype;
pFpi->fs.price;
```

The first one shows accessing a structure directly.  The second shows accessing a structure through a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

*(fpi+fpi_count).fs.name i guess